# Laravel Mail queue. Jobs getting failed

Tags: php, laravel, email, queue, laravel-5.4

Mailable

```
 public function build()
    {
        //return $this->view('view.name');

        $this->from(('mr.vishnu37@gmail.com'), 'Viz')
            ->subject('Welcome to Enterprise Solutions!')
            ->view('Mail');

        return $this;
    }
```

Controller

```
Mail::to('mr.vishnu38@yahoo.com')->queue(new TestEmail());
```

Jobs are being created but getting failed. 
queue tables are migrated
QUEUE_DRIVER set to database

Someone please help. Stuck from last two days.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error you are getting in your laravel.log ?

Comment: /var/www/html/TestLaravel/5.4.*/artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#37 {main}
"}

Comment: Tried `$this->from('mr.vishnu37@gmail.com', 'Viz')` and is the name of your blade file `Mail.blade.php` ?

Comment: as @linktoahref said where is your Mail.blade.php? If you want to you can remove the view and and debug.

Comment: There was some other error. Thanks a lot for helping out